# Tool to track classes/ids between CSS, HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, refactoring

In developing a website, I have a section structured like so:

```
    <ul id="preview-tabs" class="row nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#main-preview-pane">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#alt1-preview-pane">Alternative 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#alt2-preview-pane">Alternative 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

With corresponding CSS:

```
#preview-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8E9753;
}
```

And finally the Javascript:

```
$('#preview-tabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Now somewhere along the way I might need to change the ID of the UL to something like `design-tabs` and would have to remember to update the corresponding CSS and Javascript to maintain the functionality.

My question: is there a tool that keeps track of this relationship and can either 
1) Alert me that some linked code needs to be updated OR 
2) Do the update of the code automatically. Sort of like the Refactor feature for Java in Netbeans

Comment: Why would you need to change it?

Comment: @Hive7 if for example I'm using the Bootstrap Tabs component for the first time and apply code from a tutorial in order to get it to work and then after understanding it I'd like to name the tags in a more meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of though what you could do so that if you did update it then you wouldn't need to change your css is you could add a class to it instead of an id then target the element that way.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ctlr+shift+R to replace a selected with another text.